# In Word is it possible to have references to captions in different colour?

Tags: microsoft-word, colors, caption

References to captions are part of normal text, but they're not exactly "normal". With that in mind, and to ease on what words are captions and what are my "regular" text is it possible to have captions appear in different colour?

(Naturally, before printing I would change them back).

I have Microsoft Word 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word can highlight the field. There are three options: off, highlight when selected, and highlight always. This feature is available in all versions since Word 97 (perhaps since Word 6.0). In Word 2007 you can turn it on by

- click the Application Button
- click Word Options
- select the Advanced category
- scroll down to the Show Document Content section
- change the Field Shading setting to Always

In Word 2003 and earlier the feature is also called Field Shading.

- select Tools > Options
- select the View tab
- change the Field Shading setting to Always

The shading is not printed so you don't have to turn this off.

Comment: Excellent, even better still. I generally wanted to differentiate my "automatic stuff" from "regular text". Thanks Wayne!